# Angular Google Maps ui-gmap-google-map doesn't load the map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have simple scenario but still, doesn't work..:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>app</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Custom-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lodash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-google-maps-street-view.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">

<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

myapp.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: 'MY_API_KEY',
        // v: '3.28',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
});
```

**MainController.js**

```
myapp.controller("MainController",function ($scope,uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        $scope.maps = maps;
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 10 };
    });

});
```

**style.css**

```
ui-gmap-google-map{
    border: 1px dashed darkred;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

No errors in the console. The css is applying ok, the promise in the controller is working ok but no map is displayed.

The fact that the DOM is staying like that is bothering me :

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

because on the example site I saw that angular is changing it like that :

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="angular-google-map"><div class="angular-google-map-container">
</div><div ng-transclude="" style="display: none"></div></div></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

(or something like that)

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the problem, its because I have also included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-google-maps-street-view.js"></script>
```

After removing it, everything starts working normal.

Answer (score 2):

Since your map is loading inside a promise, try using `ng-if` to render it conditionally (as specified [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1849#issuecomment-239253464)):

```
<ui-gmap-google-map ng-if='map.center' 
                   center='map.center' 
                   zoom='map.zoom'>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2vj5JGGoUV0ePtIt9nt?p=preview).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me and the problem stays the same.... I just copy/paste your code and doesn't work :O

Comment: Actually once I reloaded the screen it loads the map... but just once :O its strange... very strange